# UnicodeDecodeError when accessing a file only occurs when fetching it from inside of an loop

Tags: python, json, for-loop, debugging, unicode

I have encountered an error when looping through a list of files. The Error only occurs when I run it through the loop.

I have made sure all the files are valid and I have ran the code below replacing x from the for loop with a integer and it worked fine all of the sudden.

```
src = open(SF_list[x]).read()
SE.data = SFC.decrypt(src)
print(f'[{x}] - {SE.getName()}({SF_names[x]})')
```

Maybe you guys can help me out, Thanks in advance!

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\PROJECT\Interface.py", line 19, in <module>
    SE.data = SFC.decrypt(src)
  File "c:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\PROJECT\SFCrypto.py", line 19, in decrypt
    return json.loads(save)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Interface.py

```
import SFCrypto as SFC

SF_folder = os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA')+'\EXAMPLEPATH'
SF_list = glob.glob(SF_folder + "/*.FILEENDING")
SF_names = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0] for file in SF_list]

vault = ''

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if vault == '':
        for x in range(SF_list.__len__()):
            src = open(SF_list[x]).read()
            SE.data = SFC.decrypt(src)
            print(f'[{x}] - {SE.getName()}({SF_names[x]})')
```

SFCrypto:

```
def decrypt(save: str) -> dict:
  save = base64.b64decode(save)
  save = CIPHER.decrypt(save)
  padding_symbol = save[-1]
  if padding_symbol < 16:
    save = save[:-padding_symbol]
  return json.loads(save)


def encrypt(save: dict) -> str:
  save = json.dumps(save, separators=(',', ':'))
  save = save.encode()
  tail = len(save) % 16
  if tail > 0:
    padding_symbol = 16 - tail
    save += bytes((padding_symbol,)) * padding_symbol
  save = CIPHER.encrypt(save)
  return base64.b64encode(save).decode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug. It occurs when decrypting multiple files from the same "CIPHER" using AES.new(), I put this within the same function instead of global and it works fine now.